# How to assign [N * 1 * M] values to only the diagonals of a [N*M*M] array?

Tags: python, numpy

I am importing data that comes in a list of N 1D arrays of [x,y,z] and I want to assign them to the diagonals of an N-dimensional array of shape [N,3,3].

The below works... it is very slow due to the loop.
Is there a better way to do this via matrix operations?

```
import numpy as np
a=np.arange(6).reshape(2,3,1)
I=np.zeros((2,3,3))
points=a.shape[0]
for step in range(points):
    np.fill_diagonal(I[step],a[step]
print(I)

  [[[0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 1., 0.],
    [0., 0., 2.]],

   [[3., 0., 0.],
    [0., 4., 0.],
    [0., 0., 5.]]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`np.einsum` should be rather efficient here:

```
a=np.arange(6).reshape(2,3,1)
I=np.zeros((2,3,3))

np.einsum("ijj->ij",I)[...] = a[...,0]

I
# array([[[0., 0., 0.],
#         [0., 1., 0.],
#         [0., 0., 2.]],
#
#        [[3., 0., 0.],
#         [0., 4., 0.],
#         [0., 0., 5.]]])
```

Simple benchmarking:

```
import numpy as np
from timeit import timeit

def embed_einsum(a):
    n,m = a.shape
    out = np.zeros((n,m,m),a.dtype)
    np.einsum("ijj->ij",out)[...] = a                        
    return out

def embed_fancy_idx(a):
    n,m = a.shape
    out = np.zeros((n,m,m),a.dtype)
    idx = np.arange(m)
    out[:,idx,idx] = a
    return out

a = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)
assert (embed_einsum(a)==embed_fancy_idx(a)).all()

for a in (np.arange(3*n).reshape(n,3) for n in (2,200,20000,2000000)):
          print("a.shape =",a.shape)
          print('einsum',timeit(lambda:embed_einsum(a),number=10)*100,'ms')
          print('fancy indexing',
                timeit(lambda:embed_fancy_idx(a),number=10)*100,'ms')
```

Result:

```
a.shape = (2, 3)
einsum 0.004329100192990154 ms
fancy indexing 0.005347799742594361 ms
a.shape = (200, 3)
einsum 0.00677639982313849 ms
fancy indexing 0.005546100146602839 ms
a.shape = (20000, 3)
einsum 0.30451889979303814 ms
fancy indexing 0.2589278003142681 ms
a.shape = (2000000, 3)
einsum 57.06863939994946 ms
fancy indexing 106.78901110004517 ms
```

`einsum` comes out on top for very large operands, but @ddejohn's method is faster for up to ~100000 elements on my rig.

Comment: Einsum is so cool. This ends up a tad slower than my approach. Haven't checked memory though.

Comment: Not on my machine, it doesn't. For example with 2,000,000 x 3 sized _a_ this comes out almost twice as fast as your method. I'll post what I did in a minute so you can check it.

Comment: Interesting. My tests were from `(10000, 3, 3)` to `(100000, 3, 3)`. But yeah, yours pulls ahead when you start getting into the millions.

Comment: That maks sense,`einsum` has a rather larger fixed overhead but uses a strided view of the diagonals which is about as  efficient as it gets. Fancy indexing has less fixed  overhed but also a penalty for the indirection that scales with operand size.

Comment: I always forget about `einsum` because it still kind of eludes me. I get the concept but I always struggle to actually apply it. The `Ellipsis` here is throwing me off.

Comment: That is just a technicality to force writing into the thing that einsum returns. Without it it is a syntax error because we would be trying to assign to a function call.

Comment: This is amazing, but einsum is very opaque to me. I sort of understand the other method, so thank you also ddejohn. I'll be using that one.

Comment: @oddroj if that's the case, can you accept my answer by clicking on the check mark? That way your question will be removed from the unanswered queue. Glad we could help.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one approach (note that you should set the `dtype` to fit your needs, I used 8-bit integers for the sake of memory):

```py
I = np.zeros((2, 3, 3), dtype="uint8")
x, y, _ = I.shape
idxs = np.arange(y)

I[..., idxs, idxs] = np.arange(x * y).reshape(x, y)
```

Output:

```py
In [4]: I
Out[4]:
array([[[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 2]],

       [[3, 0, 0],
        [0, 4, 0],
        [0, 0, 5]]], dtype=uint8)
```

A slightly larger example:

```py
In [5]: I = np.zeros((3, 6, 6), dtype="uint8")

In [6]: x, y, _ = I.shape

In [7]: idxs = np.arange(y)

In [8]: I[..., idxs, idxs] = np.arange(x * y).reshape(x, y)

In [9]: I
Out[9]: 
array([[[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
        [ 0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  2,  0,  0,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  0,  3,  0,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  4,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  5]],

       [[ 6,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
        [ 0,  7,  0,  0,  0,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  8,  0,  0,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  0,  9,  0,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  0,  0, 10,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 11]],

       [[12,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
        [ 0, 13,  0,  0,  0,  0],
        [ 0,  0, 14,  0,  0,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  0, 15,  0,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  0,  0, 16,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 17]]], dtype=uint8)
```

Some basic benchmarking:

```py
In [10]: I = np.zeros((10000, 3, 3), dtype="uint8")

In [11]: x, y, _ = I.shape

In [12]: idxs = np.arange(y)

In [13]: %timeit I[..., idxs, idxs] = np.arange(x * y).reshape(x, y)
26.6 µs ± 61.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```